# Get readable PDF content received in email as attachment

Tags: power-automate

I am struggling to get PDF content properly which is received as attachment .

[image]

[image]

Output :

[image]

Can anyone help me how to get proper readable PDF content from email attachment ?

Comment: It’s a PDF, you can’t just read it as text. Have a look for connectors that deal with it, simple.

Answer (score 0):

To transform PDF to text, you have to use a connector. You cannot transform the binary content to base64. For example, **AI Builder** from Microsoft can help to transform image or PDF to text (license is required). But there is also other connector from various vendor.

Sample : [Extract text from images or PDF documents using AI Builder Text Recognition
By Microsoft](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/c13f638e43674c5cb42a330ad69fbdb3/extract-text-from-images-or-pdf-documents-using-ai-builder-text-recognition/)

> Use Text Recognition from AI Builder to automatically process text from images and PDF documents on button click. First time using AI Builder Text Recognition? Learn more at https://aka.ms/LearnTextRecognition